# Density of Nested Subspaces Counter Example

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Suppose $ (X,||.||_{X}) $, $ (Y,||.||_{Y}) $ and $ (Z,||.||_{Z}) $ are normed vector spaces such that $ Z \subseteq Y \subseteq X $. Suppose that $Z$ is dense in $ (Y,||.||_{Y}) $ and $Y$ is dense in $ (X,||.||_{X}) $. We know that if there exists $C \in \mathbb{R} $ such that

$$ ||y||_{X} \leq C||y||_{Y}  \quad \text{for all }y\in Y\tag⋆$$ then $Z$ is also dense in $ (X,||.||_{X}) $.

I'm looking for a counter example if $(\star)$ fails. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: First of all it looks like $(\star)$ is backwards and should read $\|y\|_X \leq C\|y\|_Y$. Secondly you should show what you tried so far. For a hint, try some subspaces of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ and play around with uniform and $L^2$ norms on them.

Comment: Thanks @Shalop I've edited the post!

Answer (score 0):

Let $X=(C[a,b],\|\cdot\|_{\infty}),~Y=(C[a,b],\|\cdot\|_{2})$ and $Z$ be the subset of Y, consisting of functions with property $f(0)=0$. It is dense in $Y$ with $L^2$ norm, but it's closed in $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ norm.

Answer (score 0):

Another example:

Let $X=(L^1[a,b],∥⋅∥_∞),Y=(L^1[a,b],∥⋅∥_1)$ and $Z=C[a,b]$.

$Z$ is dense in $Y$ with $∥⋅∥_1$ norm, but it's closed in $X$ with $∥⋅∥_∞$ norm.